# ArrayList for loop iterator causing infinite loop

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, iterator

I'm trying to iterate through an ArrayList and print each element in it but it only outputs the first element in the ArrayList. Then there's an infinite loop and it keeps printing out the first element.

```
ArrayList<String> startTime = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i = 0; i < startTime.size(); i++) {
    String getTime = startTime.get(i);
    getTime = convertTime(getTime);
    startTime.add(i, getTime);
    System.out.println(startTime.get(i));
}
```

Comment: That's because you are calling `startTime.add(i, getTime);` in the loop - you are adding an element to the list in each iteration of the loop. Why did you add that line? Remove it.

Comment: Given the code here, I don't know why you would expect anything different, you are accessing the arraylist, then adding to it. Hence, infinity.

Comment: This is because you are getting data, overwriting it, getting data, overwriting it etc again and again upto infinity. There is no end. Maybe you can put an if else condition when you reach a certain benchmark and break there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `startTime.add(i, getTime)` you are adding an element in the `i` position. That means in your next iteration, you are going to have an extra element in your list. When you increment the counter and check `startTime.size()`, it's always going to be `true`. Hence your infinite loop.

As a suggestion, if you want to add your `getTime` element, you might want to use some sort of auxiliary structure, like another List.

Answer (score 1):

Definitly use advanced for-loops:

```
ArrayList<String> startTime = new ArrayList<String>();
for(String aStartTime: startTime){
  // do something
}
```

Comment: That may solve his looping problem, but it isn't going to solve the desired update behavior the op is clearly looking for.

Comment: Hi @DejaVuSansMono, thank you for your feedback. I have not understood what the op tries to achieve. The code does not make sense for me and the text could be more expressive.

Comment: That's fair. OP didn't do a good job explaining the desired behavior. I may be interpreting it wrong myself.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this for-loop:

```
for(int i=0,n=startTime.size();i<n;i++){
    //your for-loop code here  

}
```

When you were adding elements to `startTime`, it was increasing its size. Therefore, it upped the boundary that `i` had to meet infinitely.  In my example, `n` will be set to `startTime`'s size at the beginning of the loop and won't change as the loop executes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing the loop backward (from the last element to the first element ) such as:

```
// assume that I have ArrayList variable named *list*

for(int i = list.size() - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--){
    list.add(//something);
}
```

this code won't give you an infinite loop since the loop control variable never going to change ( i >= 0 ) even though your list size keeps changing. The lower bound will always be 0 and the **i** will decrease towards 0